# Java: Function that parses XML data - nothing being outputted

Tags: java, xml

I'm relatively new to XML processing with Java, so expect some mistakes, but anyway...I'm trying to parse the following XML data:

**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762271(v=vs.85).aspx**

I would like to accomplish this using a function, where the name of the XML tag and NodeList are passed in as parameters, and it returns the content.

Thanks.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Files {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")

    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException{

    String address = "/home/leo/workspace/Test/Files/src/file.xml";

String author = "author";
String title = "title";
String genre = "genre";
String price = "price";
String publish = "publish_date";
String descr = "description";


    File xmlFile = new File(address);

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    System.out.println(doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
    NodeList n = doc.getElementsByTagName("book");
    System.out.println("Number of books " + n.getLength());

    getElement(author, n);

        }

    private static void getElement(String elementName, NodeList n){

            for (int i = 0; i < n.getLength(); i++){
            Node showNode = n.item(i);

            Element showElement = (Element)showNode;

            System.out.println(elementName + ": " +
            showElement.getAttribute(elementName)

            );

        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: fine, what's the issue ?

Comment: Nothing is appearing, besides the text of elementName

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is : showElement.getAttribute(elementName)

you want to get the value of a node,but getAttribute is to get the attribute of the node,you should figure out what attribute means in XML.

you can get the value like this:

```
private static void getElement(String elementName, NodeList n){

    for (int i = 0; i < n.getLength(); i++){
        Node showNode = n.item(i);

        NodeList nl = showNode.getChildNodes();
        for(int j=0;j<nl.getLength();j++)
        {
            Node nd=nl.item(j);
            if(nd.getNodeName().equals(elementName))
            {
                 System.out.println(elementName + ":" + nd.getTextContent());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}